# Default behaviour of Jenkins for keeping builds and artifacts

Tags: jenkins

Does Jenkins by default keeps all the builds and artifacts generated in each build. Or it deletes them after a certain period of time. I know I can configure the "Discard Old builds" option, but I want to know the Jenkins default behavior.

Comment: Reading on the job configuration page, looks like Jenkins keeps all the builds and artifacts unless we configure otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Default is to keep all builds and artifacts. Might add that I don't know of any plugin which alters this default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

As far I can determine with current Jenkins, default is:

- keep the build logs forever.
- assuming you have an "archive artifacts" post-build step, keep artifacts for one month.
- keep artifacts even if build failed or was aborted.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins doesn't keep the artifacts. Jenkins only keeps the build history, means the log of the build and meta information like buildumber, time etc.

If you want that jenkins keeps your artifacts, you have to archive them.
You do this by using the archive step in your job config or by using the https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#archive-archive-artifacts step in your Jenkinsfile.

But Jenkins is not a artifact archive tool. Best is to use an artifact archiving tool, like http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/ or https://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/.